# Assign a textbox value to a variable in HTML Body and pass to several functions

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, textbox

Suppose that I have several buttons and 1 textbox on my page.

Each button is calling a different function in JS but they pass the value of the same textbox to that function.

I need to retrieve the value of the textbox once, assign it to a variable and the from there, pass the variable to the functions. So instead of writing "document.getElementById('textbox1').value" each time to pass to the functions, just pass the variable name.

*So instead of this:*

```
\<input type="button" value="button1" onclick="function**1**(document.getElementById('textbox1').value)"/>

\<input type="button" value="button1" onclick="function**2**(document.getElementById('textbox1').value)"/>
```

*I want to see this*

```
x = document.getElementById('textbox1').value # **THIS IS THE LINE I DON"T KNOW HOW TO DEFINE**

\<input type="button" value="button1" onclick="function**1**(x)"/>

\<input type="button" value="button1" onclick="function**2**(x)"/>
```

Comment: Why do you want to write inline JavaScript?! just add a script tag and write your code in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's "change" event handler and get the input value. Then bind it to a variable and use in any function. You don't need to pass it as a parameter because it is already defined at the top. and you can refer it inside the function.

```js
var funcParam = "";
$("#textbox1").change(function(){
  funcParam = $("#textbox1").val();
});

function function1(){
  console.log(funcParam)
}

function function2(){
  console.log(funcParam)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
<input type="button" value="button1" onclick="function1()"/>
<input type="button" value="button2" onclick="function2()"/>
</html>
```